# Question about r(t), movement along line

Tags: calculus, algebraic-curves

So I'm studying for an exam in calculus when i came across the concept of objects moving along a curve. I have a general idea of how to calculate speed, velocity and such when r(t)(position vector I think it is called) is given, but I can not quite understand how to determine r(t) myself.

As an example:

> $r = r(t) = x(t)i+y(t)j+z(t)k$

Then if I have $y=x^2$ should not $r=x^2i - yj$? The book says $r=xi+x^2j$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parametrize the curve, i.e., insert another variable lets call it $t$ to describe the x-axis and y-axis in terms of $t$. In our case we can let $x(t) = t$. Thus $y(t) = t^2$. So our curve is $r(t) = t i + t^2 j$. 
Different curves needs different parametrizes.